# 401 and 404 error when validation error happen

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

today I faced an error, I did solve it, but I am having trouble understanding why the error happens that way.

so I was just experimenting with Spring Boot and building a sample application with @RestController, I used "spring-boot-starter-validation" as my user input validation.

my restcontroller endpoint method is like this

```
    @PostMapping("/newEmployee")
    @ApiOperation(value = "creates a new employee",
        response =EmployeeDTO.class)
    public EmployeeDTO newEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDTO newEmployee) {
        employeeValidator.validateEmployeeDTO(newEmployee);
        return employeeManagementBO.saveOrUpdateEmployee(newEmployee);
    }
```

then I defined a handler method like below

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    //note that if @ResponseBody is not annotated here, you may get weird error like 404 or 401
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        System.out.println("error caught...");
        return errors;
    }
```

so if I remove the @ResponseBody, when I test the endpoint with PostMan, I get error code 404 (but I did debug and saw that the handler method ran), which means that after errors were returned I get 404 error.
however, if I annotate it with @ResponseBody, then everything work as expected and I get a JSON response body back with the expected error structure in a map.

so I can make sense of the @ResponseBody making my return value as the Response of my endpoint, but my question is how does the 404 error happen? also, if I make the return type a String, then I get a 405 error (saying 'POST' is not allowed).

does anybody knows without the @ResponseBody, what is happening? and is there any usecase for not annotating it with @ResponseBody?

Comment: 'is there any usecase for not annotating it with @ResponseBody' - well, yeah, for instance returning the name of the view to render. Spring MVC is not only about REST. It makes perfect sense that if Spring cannot resolve the return value as a view, it returns 404

Comment: thanks! didn't think about it like that.